# Getting the url from a request

Tags: python, django

Here's my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from stories.views import check, post

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('^.*/$', check),
]
```

And here's my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime
from models import Story

from .forms import StoryForm

def check(request):
    try:
        existing_story = Story.objects.get(name=?URLRequested?)
    except Story.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(post(request))

    HttpResponse(existing_story.text)
```

I want to convert the url entered that redirects the 404 and use it as the name for a new object. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most common way would be to make a parameter in your url, although `.*` is a very broad regex expression

```
url('^(?P<parameter_name>.*)/$', check),

def check(request, parameter_name):    
    try:
        existing_story = Story.objects.get(name=parameter_name)
```

More commonly is to look for a specific match such as `\w+` to look for a string of text of a name or similar.

See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) for more information